# Non-Serializable Object not included, still I get an error Message

Tags: java, arrays, serialization

When i write an ArrayList containing this class to a file, I get the Error that "Location is not Serializable", yet this doesn't contain an Location. Do you have ideas what that could be?

```
class PortalShard implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private DyeColor c;

    private String worldName;
    private double X;
    private double Y;
    private double Z;


    public PortalShard(Location l, DyeColor c) {
        this.c = c;
        worldName = l.getWorld().getName();
        X = l.getX();
        Y = l.getY();
        Z = l.getZ();
    }
    public Location getLocation() {
        return (new Location(getServer().getWorld(worldName), X, Y, Z));
    }
    public DyeColor getDyeColor() {
        return c;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        Location l = new Location(getServer().getWorld(worldName), X, Y, Z);
        if (l.add(0, -1, 0).getBlock().getType().equals(Material.WOOL) && l.add(0, -2, 0).getBlock().getType().equals(Material.IRON_BLOCK)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

EDIT

Here's the class above which has two Portal Shards each, Portal:

```
class Portal implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3488849683057792945L;

    DyeColor c;

    PortalShard p1;
    PortalShard p2;

    public ArrayList<PortalShard> getPortalShards() {
        return new ArrayList<PortalShard>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; {add(p1); add(p2);}};
    }

    public Portal(PortalShard p1, PortalShard p2) {
        if (p1.getDyeColor().equals(p2.getDyeColor())) {
            this.p1 = p1;
            this.p2 = p2;
            c = p1.getDyeColor();
        }
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        if (p1.isActive() && p2.isActive()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void teleport(Location l, Player p) {
        if (l.equals(p1.getLocation())) {
            p.teleport(p2.getLocation());
        }
        if (l.equals(p2.getLocation())) {
            p.teleport(p1.getLocation());
        }
    }
}
```

And the method to save the lists:

```
private void saveFiles() {
    File f = new File(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));File dir = f.getAbsoluteFile().getParentFile();String path = dir.toString();
    try {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> readCards = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream(path + "/plugins/portals/portals.txt");
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileout);
        out.writeObject(portals);
        out.close();
        fileout.close();
        FileOutputStream fileout2 = new FileOutputStream(path + "/plugins/portals/portalshards.txt");
        ObjectOutputStream out2 = new ObjectOutputStream(fileout2);
        out2.writeObject(portalShards);
        out2.close();
        fileout2.close();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

(Sorry, I'm a noob in Java. When i do something unnecessary, please don't hate D:
Thanks for your help so far!)

Comment: Stack trace, please.

Comment: I hope I have put in everything nessecary now.

Comment: No, you haven't put in everything necessary now. You haven't put in the stack trace that was specifically requested by @chrylis. This is needed for a reason. It should have been included in the first place. Edit it into your question. NB serialized files are not text: don't give them text-file extensions.

Comment: From @mojtaba357 (not enough rep to comment) : did you implement Serializable Interface for DyeColor class?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you aren't running this code. I suggest you're running a version of the code where `Location` is a non-transient instance member of `PortalShard`.

Comment: I got it now. In the superclass, there was a Location and Player object. I created them as independent classes and it worked.